# DaisyUI not loading style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, postcss, ruby-on-rails-7, daisyui

Working on Rails 7 app where I added postcss and Tailwind, removed redundant tailwind gem and tailwind `stylesheet_link_tag` in the `application.html.erb`.

My problem starts when I wanted to include DaisyUI components. The install guide is pretty straightforward so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've added daisyui to plugins and added it through yarn.

Here is my setup, `config/tailwind.config.js`:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
    require('daisyui'),
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "daisyui": "^2.51.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify"
  }
}
```

Running bin/dev:
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?